# Error on LoadURL with TChromium

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, tchromium

I found the brilliant [Delphi Chromium](http://code.google.com/p/delphichromiumembedded/) project for embedding Chrome in a Delphi form.  It works well in Delphi7 after a bit of hacking and I can get the demo app running.

However when I do my own app with the component, I can't load my own url.  I get a access violation.

```
Chromium2.Browser.MainFrame.LoadUrl('http://www.example.com');
```

The TChromium component is working and I have all the DLLs in the right place, since if I set `DefaultUrl` it works fine.

I have Chromium2 in a TPageControl page and with the OnClick event of a button I call the above code.  I get an AccessViolation.  Mainframe is `nil`.

I can't find a way around this, has anyone got this to work?

Comment: Have you looked at the source? Where is MainFrame meant to be created?

Comment: You don't have to create it manually.. and as he gets the AV on a button's click (so, not in the formcreate...), I'm 99% sure this is linked to the missing DLL ;o)

Comment: @Whiler, I don't think I'm missing DLLs.  It works with defaultUrl property.

Comment: I have AVs in almost every URL i try to open. I'm using Delphi 2007, all dlls in the right place. TChromium generates cascade AVs and crashes the app. Any ideas ?

Comment: @delphirules please ask a new question

Comment: I asked on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34199324/delphi-tchromium-dcef3-constant-access-violations?noredirect=1#comment56165145_34199324

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I still haven't found a resolution but I found the following work around

```
procedure TForm1.lblWebsiteClick(Sender: TObject);
var MainFrame : ICefFrame;
begin
  MainFrame := Chromium2.Browser.GetMainFrame;
  MainFrame.LoadUrl('http://www.cookingisfun.ie');
end;
```

Comment: That does not look like a workaround. That looks like how it is meant to be used. Front page of documentation says "CefFrame represents a single frame in the browser window. Each browser window also has a top-level main frame that can be accessed via the CefBrowser::GetMainFrame() method."

Comment: @David, the code in the Demo apps uses the code in the structure I origionally tried `Chromium2.Browser.MainFrame.LoadUrl('http://www.example.com');` so presumably the author felt this was the way it was meant to be used.

Comment: You've got the source. I don't. It should be easy to see where MainFrame gets allocated (or not).

Comment: I don't need this workaround in my own project. `Chromium2.Browser.MainFrame.LoadUrl('http://www.example.com');` works as expected with mine. I have no `DefaultUrl` defined.. that's maybe the difference.

Comment: Its fairly odd alright.  It may be something to do with running Delphi 7 on a Windows 7 machine.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that mainframe only loads after the page has loaded.

For one thing, you need to do:

```
if Assigned(Chromium2.Browser.MainFrame)
    then  Chromium2.Browser.MainFrame...
```

However, that is not the preferred way to navigate, but instead you should do:

```
Chromium1.Load( theUrl );
```

If you still want to use `MainFrame`, do it in `OnLoadEnd` event.

Comment: Chromium1.Load does the same as above. It just fails silently when MainFrame is nil.

Answer (score 2):

Had similar problems and after quite a few hours located the problem:

1. If TChromium is on the main form of the application then ok.
2. If TChromium is not on main form (or on a frame) then:

   1. Open cef.inc and remove the dot to define:

      ```
      {.$DEFINE CEF_MULTI_THREADED_MESSAGE_LOOP}
      ```
   2. Remove DefaultURL value so it is an empty string.

I googled CEF_MULTI_THREADED_MESSAGE_LOOP but it didn't come up with much at all.

Lastly, had resizing/refreshing problems (even with alignment set to alClient). Short term fix is within
crmLoadEnd event do something like:

```
     if crm.Height < panclient.Height then
        crm.Height := panclient.Height;
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have alll the required DLL in the folder where your application is built?

You need: libcef.dll, icudt.dll, ...

Check this [thread](http://groups.google.com/group/delphichromiumembedded/browse_thread/thread/f7ef3f217e1c4073) on their support group.

---

When you build/run the demos, they are built in this subfolder (*DCC_ExeOutput*): DCEF\bin\
which is why it works with them...

Comment: @David: if they are loaded dynamically and GetProcAddress returns nil, it could.

Comment: @Rudy `GetProcAddress` returning `nil` seems unlikely to lead to `MainFrame` being `nil`. `MainFrame` sounds like a component to me rather than a procedure address. What makes you think it is a procedure address? What am I missing?

Comment: I use this component and if I remove the DLL from my executable folder, I have this behaviour... so, I think this is the reason why he gets this AV...

Comment: MainFrame is set to `nil` when DLLs are missing, but is assigned if they are there? Really?

Comment: I **think** that `MainFrame` is not instanciate when dll are missing... and if DLL are present, it is automatically instanciate... BTW, my code is always prefix with   `if (chrm1.Browser <> nil) then`
before each method calls...

Comment: I'll take your word for it but it seems unusual. Binding errors usually result in bind time errors.

Comment: All the dlls are in place,  the exe is built to the bin directory with the dlls.  If I set DefaultUrl it works and loads the url, but I cant set my own url.  Browser isnt nil, mainframe is.

Comment: @Toby: That's weird... See my other comment in your answer

Answer (score 0):

Had this problem as well. It seems the MainFrame is first created when the frame/window gets visible.
But there is an easy way around it. Just call .Load('about:blank') directly on your TChromium object. This will initialize the missing frame earlier.