# Delphi Chromium Embedded: ICefBrowser.GetMainFrame returns NIL

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, chromium, chromium-embedded, tchromium

I'd like to use `TChromium` component which is part of Delphi Chromium Embedded (http://code.google.com/p/delphichromiumembedded/). Unfortunately once I build the application and run it (it's inside 'bin' directory which contains all the CEF binaries, so **no, it's not about missing DLL**), the call to `Chromium.Browser.GetMainFrame` returns **NIL**, which actually stops me from using DCE at all.

WinXP 32, Delphi7PE. Any tips?

Comment: Maybe this will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7453345/error-on-loadurl-with-tchromium

Comment: @bazals, it won't help. The solution there is worthless since Chromium.Load(url) is essentially the same as MainFrame.LoadUrl().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try posting to the [DelphiChromiumEmbedded Google group](http://groups.google.com/group/delphichromiumembedded?pli=1). That group is actively monitored by Henri Gourvest, the lead programmer working on the Delphi encapsulation of CEF.