# DCEF TChromium Memory exception on start up

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, chromium, tchromium

Another continuation of my previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9587021/using-tchromium-delphi-chromium-embedded).

In my previous question the project would not run and I was told that the DLL's that come with the component were simply in the wrong place. I moved them to the areas suggested (The output folder of the project I was working on) and the project did indeed run. However, a new error quickly revealed itself, as soon as TChromium attempts to navigate to any webpage, either through the defaulturl property or by use of the LoadURL procedure, the program throws a memory exception.

In particular the error notice says:

```
Debugger Fault Notification
Project faulted with message 'access violation at 0x00000000; read of address 0x00000000'
```

This particular error occurs on the end statement of the procedure that attempts to navigate.

To me this says that something is not being initialized properly, but this is simply a test project with nothing but a TChromium component and a TButton to navigate to 'http://www.google.com' on the form.

Source:

```
unit Test2;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls, cefvcl;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Chromium1: TChromium;
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Chromium1.Browser.getmainframe.LoadUrl('http://www.google.com');
end;

end.
```

Considering I can see no forum posts, or questions of this nature on this website I can only assume this is an isolated problem, probably caused by something I myself have done wrong, but for the life of me I cannot think what.

So my question is, does anyone know what is causing this error and have I simply made my project wrong?

Comment: A [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7453345/937125)? Up-voting becouse I had the same problem myself (And numerous other exceptions with TChromium :/ ).

Comment: Seperate issues, The post you linked to says that the defaulturl property works fine, whereas mine causes the aforementioned error. You will also noticed that my code navigation code is essentially the same as the accepted answer on the page you linked to.

I was already aware of that question before I wrote my own, but thankyou for reading my question.

Comment: @TLama,  There are several answers/ideas there. this is why I added the question mark. I have had a bad experience myself with TChromium and D7, so I dumped it.